# Split testing - Ads on facebook

Tags: facebook, testing, facebook-ads-api

Split testing - Ads on facebook

Hello,

we intend to do split testing to check which of the 5 titles of our book converts better. What would be the best option for that? We tried to choose Traffic option as a goal for the campaign on Facebook, but none of the three deep options (Delivery optimization/Audience/Placement) seems right for this task. Or maybe we should just simply run 5 parallel campaigns? If so, how to force FB that they are presented to different groups of people and just once per person?

Regards
JLA

Answer (score 1):

Ok, some things to considerate:

- You must define your Traffic objective on the **Campaign Level**
- Delivery optimization, Audience, and Placement must be defined on the **Ad Set Level**
- If you want to try 5 different Ads with one title per Ad, you should do it by using the **Ad Level**

By adjusting things as I said above, you'll have:

- 1 Campaign (with the objective you want: Traffic)
- 1 Ad Set (here you set **Daily Unique Reach** on the Optimization for Ad Delivery field, to deliver the Ad once day)
- 5 Ads (Facebook will automatically optimize to deliver the ones that are better performing)